# Require is not defined Node js

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Я пытаюсь подключить puppeteer, но выдается данная ошибка, вот мой код

```
const puppeteer = require('./node_modules/puppeteer');

let scrape = async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://www.avito.ru/sankt-peterburg/koshki/poroda-meyn-kun- 
ASgBAgICAUSoA5IV/');
//await page.waitFor(1000);

const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
let title = document.querySelector('.title-root-j7cja').innerText;
let description = document.querySelector('.iva-item-text-_s_vh').innerText;

let json = {
  "title": title,
  "description": description
};

var jsonFile = JSON.stringify(json);
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("result.json", jsonFile, function(err, result) {
  if(err) console.log('error', err);
});

return {
  title,
  description
}
});


browser.close();
return result;
};

 scrape().then((value) => {
     console.log(value); // Получилось!
 });
```

[image: вот что выводится в терминал]

Как мне избежать этой ошибки?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: код, который написан внутри метода `evaluate` выполняется в браузере. Там нет ни `require`,  ни модуля `fs`

Comment: У меня проблема именно с самым первым require, в котором подключается puppeteer

Comment: Почему вы так думаете? Судя по стеку ошибки, проблема как раз внутри кода в `page.evaluate()`. Попробуйте его закомментировать и проверьте запуск без него. Или обновите сообщение об ошибке.